# How to find High CPU queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, monitoring, alerts

CPU utilization is very high and the SQL Server process is consuming a lot of CPU. We have run few queries and notice that there are a few SPIDs taking a long time to complete and these queries may be causing the high CPU pressure.  Is there any way to get queries which are taking a lot of CPU of each SQL Server process is consuming?

I want to put an alert when ever the CPU reaches to 90% above then mail an alert with high consuming queries and to get exact one among all. I got the below process to get the high cpu thread which is using the CPU more but I need it through script to get the information. How to do [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2454/how-to-find-out-how-much-cpu-a-sql-server-process-is-really-using/) by script?

SQL Server 2014
OS: Windows 2012 Server

Comment: [A good resource on queries to find queries hogging various resources.](http://michaeljswart.com/go/Top20)

Answer (score 4):

Please look at the three main queries in the following answer (of mine):

[SQL Server performance: PREEMPTIVE_OS_DELETESECURITYCONTEXT dominant wait type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60830/sql-server-performance-preemptive-os-deletesecuritycontext-dominant-wait-type/61012#61012)

The first query looks at currently running queries.

The second two queries (labeled "Query #1" and "Query #2") work in combination to find high-cost queries over a period of time.

To get alerts, look into options such as [Solarwinds Free WMI Monitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/wmi_monitor/) or [Spiceworks Network Monitor](http://www.spiceworks.com/network-monitor/windows-linux-server-monitoring/).

You need monitoring software of some nature. Those were 2 that I found for Windows that were free. Most of the free ones appear to be for Unix, or are at least Unix-based. You can also look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) and [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/). You can use the queries I provided in the linked answer with at least some of those products. But they should do the "alert on high CPU for X minutes" thing.

You could also write your own system that polls on a scheduled, is scheduled, stores data in SQL Server, ages out old data, calculates % variance over a configurable time-frame, and takes action upon that condition being met. This is *a lot* more work as you now have even more code to maintain (but is still a viable option if the above doesn't work out for you).